# if a equation is multiplied by negative, will it still be considered right?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a equation $y-6x+64=0$ and I multiply it by $-1$ so that it becomes  $-y+6x-64=0$ will it still be equal?

I substituted $1$ in place of $x$ and $1$ in place of $y$ and answer was not equal for both the equations. So according to me it is not equal.

Comment: Yes, you can multiply both sides of an equation by any constant, and equality will hold.  However, if you have an inequality, you must be more careful.  Multiplying by a negative number will flip the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $-1$ is equivalent to subtracting (LHS + RHS) from both sides, which is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Notice that (x,y) = (1,1) is not a solution to the given equation. For an (x,y) pair to be a solution, both sides of the equation must be equal when those (x,y) values are substituted in.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being "considered" right.  It is simply *right*.

Comment: When you plugged (1,1) in (x,y) it was not the same thing because (1,1) is not a solution of this equation, that is, 1-6+64=0 and -1+6-64=0 are false.

Comment: What @DougM wrote is technically true, but it should be qualified in the case of multiplying by zero. The result will be $0=0$, which is certainly true, but not equivalent to the original equation. Multiplying by a nonzero constant, on the other hand, results in an equivalent equation, because the operation can be "undone" (nonzero constants have multiplicative inverses). By "equivalent" equations I mean that they will have exactly the same solutions. In your case there's no contradiction: $(1,1)$ is not a solution to the first equation, and it's not a solution to the second equation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is completely valid to multiply both sides of the equation by $(-1)$.

The reason why inserting $1$ for both $x$ and $y$ in the equations each does not give the same resulting expressions is because $(1,1)$ is not a solution to the given equation. If you insert $(1,1)$ in the first equation you get $1-6+64=0\Leftrightarrow59=0$. In the second equation you get $-1+6-64=0\Leftrightarrow -59=0$. Both expressions are not equal, but they are both *wrong*.

However, multiplying by $(-1)$ will not change the *solutions* of the equation. e.g. $(1,-58)$ will return $0$ when inserted in either of the equations, because it is a solution to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

The equation
$$
y - 6x + 64 = 0
$$
tells you a *relation* between the values of $x$ and $y$. For particular values of $x$ and $y$ it may not be an equality of numbers.

The equation
$$
-y + 6x - 64 = 0
$$
expresses the *same relation*. It's true for particular $x$ and $y$ just when the first one is.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $(1,1)$ into your equation and equation multiplied by $-1$ would give the same result - the contradiction.

If You want to compare the results, You should substitute the solution (in your example the solutions are at form $(t,6t-64)$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, for example $(0,-64)$ or $(1, -58)$).